# How to Index the token seperated by delimeters in C and access the elements in a file using index and a search string in command line arguments

Tags: c, split

My file has been seperated using ":" deleimeter .
Now i want to index the string seperated by delimeter
And when i give index and Search String as an argument in command line, it should display the matched records

Suppose in the command line i give Argument as: 1 foo, where 1 is an index and foo is the string. so in an whole txt file each line which have index as "1", the string "foo" get should searched within index –

Moreover my text file is an Password file of Linux

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str, *saveptr;
    char ch[100];
    char *sp;
    FILE *f;
    int j;
    int index = atoi(argv[1])-1 ;
    int stringsrch = argv[2] ;

    f = fopen("passwd", "r");
    while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, f)!= NULL)
    {
        /*printf("%s\n", ch); */

        for (j = 1, str = ch; ; j++, str= NULL)
        {
             char *token = strtok_r(str, ": ", &saveptr);
             if (token == NULL)
             break;
             printf("%s\n", token);
        }
     }

    fclose(f);
```

Comment: Add example of input and expected output in your question.

Comment: suse-ncc:x:112:114:Novell Customer Center User:/var/lib/YaST2/suse-ncc-fakehome:/bin/bash
tomcat:x:111:113:Tomcat:/usr/share/tomcat55:/bin/sh
....So when index is "1", the index 1 contains suse-ncc and tomcat   ....and now when i give second argument as "tomcat" it should display the whole record of tomcat